# How to pass data from Controller method to view in Opencart 2

Tags: php, opencart2.x, opencart-module, opencart2.3

I m developing my first module in Opencart. The version I m using is 2.3.
In my controller I have the index method and another method who handles my form data. I want to make some validations not in the index method and if it has some errors I want to fill an array and pass it back to the view.Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your can pass the errors in array and then that array should be assinged in a session variable then you can get the errors on your form.